# One activity with two successor activities

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

On my main activity(start window of app) I have Button and Button_1. It doesn't matter what will click here the user will open `Activity_1`. Activity_1 is the same for both buttons. The different will be from Activity_1 depends which button is clicked must open Activity_2 or Activity_3.

Here is the scenario.

```
Button   -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2
Button_1 -> Activity 1 -> Activity 3
```

I have everything done but the part with knowing which button is clicked.

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
});
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

`Menu.class` is listview with image and text. If `Button` is clicked and open listview user is able to click on item and read some information.
If `Button_1` is clicked it load same listview and when user click on item should open different info from another activity.

Currently I'm able to successfully open `Menu.class`. There I load my listview and I can pass the info to next activity but just to one..

How can I store/know which button is pressed so according to this to load proper activity. Whit `IF`? `case`?

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    boolean isButton = getIntet().getExtra("isButtonClicked",false);
    if(isButton)
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Information.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Information1.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // Download JSON File   
    new DownloadJSONFileAsync().execute();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass button clicked information to menu activity by intent.putExtra() method like below

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("isButtonClicked",true);
    startActivity(intent);

}
});
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("isButtonClicked",false);
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

and on Menu Activity onCreate() method get the clicked button by

```
 boolean isButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isButtonClicked",false);
```

if isButton value is true then button is clicked. otherwise button1 is clicked.then start new activity by

```
   if(isButton)
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Activity2.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Activity3.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Where should be `If{}else{}` block? In activity 1?

Comment: Yes From Menu activity.Sorry Now Edited check my answer

Comment: I have updated my question what I currently have in `Menu.class` I how I pass extras to Information.class.

Comment: newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position);
 newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer);

Comment: `boolean isButton = getIntet().getExtra("isButtonClicked",false);` I get `The method getIntet() is undefined for the type Menu`

Comment: This is how it looks `onCreate` in Menu.class now. Updated my question

Comment: I have Updated My Answer Sorry I thought you Know about getIntent() method. Check Now its getIntent() not getIntet()

Comment: And now I should take different activity after second activity.

Comment: if(isButton)
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Information.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Information1.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }   Use this code when you want to start the new activity if you used it in oncreate() method then at creating Menu activity suddenly it will move to another activity

Comment: Something is not ok. The app crash on first button click and the error is from the `Information.class`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65436/discussion-between-jason-paddle-and-mathang).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `intent.putExtra("value", true);`
and in Activity 1 onCreate method

```
boolean val = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("value", false);
```

and based on val go to either Activity 2 or 3.

Comment: What must be `Value`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use extras:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("btn", 1);

Intent menu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
menu.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(menu);
```

In another activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
   Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (myBundle.getInt("btn") == 1){
      // todos
   } else if (myBundle.getInt("btn") == 2){
      // todos 
   }
}
```